# Latex warning Citation undefined event if the citation has been deleted from the code

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the package `biblatex` with `[backend=bibtex]` and the command `\cite{}` which works perfectly with my bib file linked to Mendeley. Accidentally I copy-pasted a link in the ambient `\cite{}` and now I get this error 'undefined on input' `Citation 591\IeC {\textendash}616.` + the link I accidentally copy pasted '.
Now, even deleting it from the code I get this reference as a full link on my main text when compiling.

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` file and compile again. Citation requests can persevere in the temporary files even if they are removed from the `.tex` file. Usually the should be gone after a full cycle of LaTeX, Biber/BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX, but if that does not help, deleting the temporary files should help.

Comment: Do let us know if your problem was resolved deleting the temporary files. If you could not solve your problem we need to know a bit more about what you did and if and how we can reproduce your situation exactly.

Comment: yes, it was solved by deleting the temporary files. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved be deleting the temporary files and compiling from scratch.